# How to retrieve data from generated block

Tags: blocks

On catalog page there is a block that adds paging navigation - `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager`. It has very useful methods - `getPreviousPageUrl` and `getNextPageUrl`.

Is there any way to get values from these functions outside of this block scope, without recreating it second time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the instance of a block like this:

```
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('block_name_here');
```

Then just call `$block->methodHere()`

Comment: That's right, but in the pager case you have to wait for `catalog/product_list` to start rendering. In fact, `catalog/product_list` configures the pager block in its method `_beforeToHtml()`. If you call the snippet above before `_beforeToHtml()` has executed, you would get no results or even a fatal error.