# Modify contents of head from body

Tags: blocks

Continuing [previous question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4079/how-to-retrieve-data-from-generated-block).

- I successfully retrieved a URL of the next catalog page from catalog pager block (`Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager`).
- Now I'm trying to add this URL to the head block (e.g. `<link rel="next" url="url-to-next-page" />`).

-

```
public function core_block_abstract_to_html_before(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

  $block = $observer->getBlock();

  // Check if current block is pager block
  if($block instanceof Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager) {
    // I'm getting head block
    $head_block = $Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('head');

    // Trying to add  <link rel="next" url="path-to-next-page" /> to head
    // $block->getNextPageUrl() prints correct value
    // But nothing is added to head
    $head_block->addLinkRel( 'next', $block->getNextPageUrl() );
  }

}
```

Is it possible at least, or I'm doing this in wrong way?

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is, that the `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head` is already renderer, when you iterate ober the `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager`.

You can do it the other way around. Check for `instanceof Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head` get the pager from the layout and get insert the link.

To get the pager-block in the category view, have a look into the `catalog.xml`:

```
<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
```

So to get the block:

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('product_list_toolbar_pager');
```

And because I just saw it, do you really typed `$Mage` in your code? And this worked? It should be `Mage::`

Comment: Thanks you as always. I've tried this, but `getBlock('page/html_pager')` returns false in head. Here is code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/139e7e76343285f621e5

Comment: Am I missing something?

Comment: Then the block is created later by the product list, maybe. I have no spontanous idea. Maybe tomorrow

Comment: updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that too, now it returns the block but all data in it is `null`. Probably because it hasn't been initialized yet. It looks like it's impossible to move data from body to head, so I used `createBlock` instead of `getBlock`.